# Merge cells in Excel between x and y

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in excel that varies between 5 - 6 cells long, with 3 spaces in between.

I wish to group all data between :

1. Post to:
2. x
3. x
4. x
5. x - maybe; this isnt always here
6. Australia

So all data between each instance of POST TO: and then next AUSTRALIA, merge into 1 cell. How can this be done?

The data starts in B4

Once that is done I will then run a pre-recorded macro to take that data and paste it into my label template in MS Word to then print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed it start in B4 cell

If you need easy formula in B10

```
= B15 & " " &B16 & " " & B17 & " " &B18 &" " & B19 & " " & B20
```

Or in VBA .. Set you button to Sub Test ..

```
Sub Test()
ConcatIt Range("B4")
End Sub

Sub ConcatIt(pos As Range)
Dim x, y As Integer
x = pos.Column
y = pos.Row
Cells(y + 6, x) = Cells(y, x) & " " & Cells(y + 1, x) & " " & Cells(y + 2, x) & " " & Cells(y + 3, x) & " " & Cells(y + 4, x) & " " & Cells(y + 5, x)
End Sub
```

Comment: It actaully starts at B4, forgot to add that. I made such changes and created a VBA macro and added the code, when running it nothing happens?

Comment: @user2514595 .. it's updated .. dont forget to vote this as the answer if this helps you ... :P

Comment: Of course! How do I actually add this? Thanks for the help, too. I appreciate it!

Comment: @user2514595 .. so you can change in sub test() like **ConcatIt Range("C4")** .. **ConcatIt Range("D4")** .. so on ..

Comment: Yeah I've been trying that, now it's not merging anything O.o

Comment: not merging ? .. i've been test it .. what actually your situation ?

Comment: I've generated customers addresses from ebay and pasted it into excel. 
Sorry it was never actually merging anything.

Is this a VBA macro?

Comment: Could i maybe email you the worksheet that I'm working with so you can see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have looked high and low for your email.. maybe I cannot see it due to being a new user?

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping for that macro to work as I will need to do this many times quickly. Nevermind, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to concatenate the rows you could do something like this :

```
Range("a1").Value = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("b1:b6")), Chr(9))
```

Comment: Hm, but the data varies between 5 - 6 rows long.

Comment: Do you need a loop to search through for Post To ? Does this appear multiple times ?

Comment: "Post to:" appears at the start of each customers desired address.